# How to make sed do non-greedy match?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I cannot seem to figure out how to come up with the correct regex for my bash command line.
Here's what I am doing:

```
echo "XML-Xerces-2.7.0-0.tar.gz" | sed -e's/^\(.*\)-[0-9].*/\1/g'
```

This gives me the output of ...

```
XML-Xerces-2.7.0
```

... but want I need is the output to be ...

```
XML-Xerces
```

... I guess I could do this ...

```
 echo "XML-Xerces-2.7.0-0.tar.gz" | sed -e's/^\(.*\)-[0-9].*/\1/g' | sed -e's/^\(.*\)-[0-9].*/\1/g'
```

... but I would like to know how understand `sed` regex a little better.

Update:

I tried this ...

```
echo "XML-Xerces-2.7.0-0.tar.gz" | sed -e's/^\([^-]*\)-[0-9].*/\1/g'
```

... as suggest but that outputs `XML-Xerces-2.7.0-0.tar.gz`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do non greedy regex in sed, but you can do something like this instead:

```
echo "XML-Xerces-2.7.0-0.tar.gz" | sed -e 's/^\(\([^-]\|-[^0-9]\)*\).*/\1/g'
```

Which will capture everything up until it finds a `-` followed by `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't sed when you're in bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
V='XML-Xerces-2.7.0-0.tar.gz'
echo "${V%%-+([0-9]).+([0-9])*}"
```

Comment: Pretty slick! But I am not sure I understand how to read `${V%%-+([0-9]).+([0-9])*}`.  Could you explain that part?

Comment: @RedCricket It's an extended glob. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html). The feature is not enabled by default and we enable it through `shopt -s extglob`. The expansion method of the variable deletes the match found in the end of the variable's value. Expansion methods are explained [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). The pattern `-+([0-9]).+([0-9])*` matches `-2.7.0-0.tar.gz` of `XML-Xerces-2.7.0-0.tar.gz` and so that part is deleted. In regex it's actually like `-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.*$`.