# Using pattern in Shell Parameter Expansion

Tags: bash

I am reading a page and trying to extract some data from it. I am interested in using bash and after going through few links, i came to know that 'Shell Parameter Expansion' might help however, i am finding difficulty using it in my script. I know that using *sed* might be easier but just for my knowledge i want to know how can i achieve this in *bash*.

```
shopt -s extglob

str='My work</u><br /><span style="color: rgb(34,34,34);"></span><span>abc-X7-27ABC | </span><span style="color: rgb(34,34,34);">build'
echo "${str//<.*>/|}"
```

I want my output to be like this: `My work|abc-X7-27ABC |build`

I thought of checking whether it accepts only word instead of pattern and it seems to be working with words.

For instance,
`echo "${str//span style/|}"` works but
`echo "${str//span.*style/|}"` doesn't

On the other hand, i saw in one of the link that it *does* accept pattern. I am confused why it's not working with the patern i am using above.

[How to make sed do non-greedy match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791351/how-to-make-sed-do-non-greedy-match)
(User konsolebox's solution)

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have a `|` character in the `abc ...` part?

Comment: | character will not be there initially. You can ignore it. All i want is to remove everything _before_ and _after_ the following words: _My work_, _abc-X7-27ABC_ and _build_. While i am removing the HTML syntax, i would like to have | as the replacement character. The output should, therefore, look like `My work|abc-X7-27ABC |build`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One mistake you're making is by mixing shell globbing and regex. In `shell glob` dot is taken literally as dot character not as 0 or more of any character.

If you try this code instead:

```
echo "${str//<*>/|}"
```

then it will print:

```
My work|build
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for pointing it out. Now the issue is that i am not getting the result i actually want. It's doing a greedy match. Is there any way i can use something like '${parameter%word}' to get the output i want in bash: `My work|abc-X7-27ABC |build`?

Comment: @Technext: I am on mobile at present. When I get back to my computer I will play with your input text to see if I can get the desired output.

Comment: The problem here is that you don't want a greedy match here (which eats up everything from the `</u>` tag to the `<span>` prior to "build"), but you also don't want a non-greedy match (which would result in too many substitutions: "My work|||||abc-X7-27ABC | ||build". The same advice that goes for regular expressions and HTML parsing ("Don't. Use a proper HTML parser.") applies even more so for shell patterns, which are less powerful and primarily intended for matching simple sets of file names.

Comment: @Technext: See detailed comment from `Chepner` above. It is not a good idea to parse HTML like this using shell utilities. Using a DOM parser like in PHP should be ideal way.

Comment: Thanks @chepner & anubhava for your comments. I also got stuck with the following output: "My work|||||abc-X7-27ABC | ||build". Can the output be achieved with sed or awk or Perl?

Comment: @Technext: If you got above string you can pipe it to another sed like: `echo "My work|||||abc-X7-27ABC | ||build" | sed 's/ *| *| *//g'` to get `My work|abc-X7-27ABC|build`

Comment: You're welcome. If you think my answer helped you anyway please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, so much as a demonstration of why pattern-matching is not recommended for this kind of HTML editing. I attempted the following.

```
shopt -s extglob
set +H    # Turn off history expansion, if necessary, to allow the !(...) pattern
echo ${str//+(<+(!(>))>)/|}
```

First: it didn't work, even for a simpler string like `str='My work</u><br />bob<foo>build'`. Second, for the string in the original question, it appeared to lock up the shell; I suspect such a complex pattern triggers exponential backtracking.

Here's how it's intended to work:

1. `!(>)` is any thing other than a single `>`
2. `+(!(>))` is one or more non-`>` characters.
3. `<+(!(>))>` is one or more non-`>` characters enclosed in `<` and `>`
4. `+(<+(!(>))>)` is one or more groups of `<...>`-enclosed non-`>`s.

My theory is that since `!(>)` can match a multi-character string as well as a single character, there is a *ton* of backtracking required.